# Filling horizontal list with multiple list elements

Tags: html, css

So I need to make a horizontal list where the first list element has a fixed width and the last list element should fill the available width. Problem is that the last element fills the entire row even though I've set `width` for the first element. Why the 2nd element ignores the first elements width?

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
       <li />
       <li />
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
}

ul {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

li:first-child {
    background:red;
    width: 30px;
}

li:last-child {
    background:blue;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the answers! I later noticed that if I add `min-width` to the first `li` I get what i want.

Answer (score 2):

In your JSFiddle, you told the last `li` element should use the whole width

```
li:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can omit the width property, because it will use the remaining width anyway. See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XRc66/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your css:

```
li:first-child{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Regards :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't set `width` for the last element.

If you don't set CSS `width` property it is set to the default value, `auto`. Doing so you get the expected result, give a look at Olaf Dietsche's fiddle.

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer?

Comment: If you don't set CSS `width` property it is set to the default value, `auto`. Doing so you get the expected result, give a look at Olaf Dietsche's fiddle.